# JVM Args in java web start application

Tags: java-8, javafx-2, java-web-start, jnlp, jvm-arguments

I have a Javafx application which is deploybed via java webstart.

I need to pass GC vm args for the application and I have issues in doing so.

I have the following in my jnlp

```
<j2se version="1.8+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="1024m" max-heap-size="1024m" java-vm-args="-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"/>
```

When the application starts, it looks like most of them are **not passed** to the VM

ps -ef | grep java gives the below output

133768645  2448     1   0  4:31PM ttys020    0:37.80 /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java **-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -Xmx1g -Xms1g**

The min & max heap gets set as expected but not all the other VM arguments.

Can u please let me know why the other vm args are not being passed to the VM ?
Am I doing something wrong ?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Examples of how to provide java vm arguments when packaging a JavaFX application are provided in the [JavaFX deployment documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIAEEFCJ).

Comment: I think those `java-vm-args` are not allowed, see the [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources). I never used JavaFX but I doubt this could make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jnlp file that you changed is the one javaws is using. If it has an href attribute in the jnlp file header, it will take the jnlp file from there even if you launch it from your local machine.